# One-to-many relationship in the create action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working on a project that requires add multiple addresses for one client. 
I have three models: 
here is a link to my class diagram: http://sdrv.ms/1fWioA2

Person model:

```
public class Person
{    
    public Person()
    {
        this.Adresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required")]
    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    //[RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",
    //ErrorMessage = "Email is is not valid.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Adresses { get; set; }
}
```

address:

```
public class Address
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Building  { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int CityID { get; set; }

    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

I created modelview to bind to my Create view:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Adresses { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how to bind the viewmodel to the create view in order to be able to save multiple addresses for the same Person?

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, create an editor template in `/Shared/Editor` called `Address.cshtml`:

```
@model Address

<div class="address">
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CityID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Street) <br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Building  ) <br />
</div>
```

Now, in your `View`, all you need to do is this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(v => v.Addresses)
```

This will create form fields like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="address[0].Id" />
<input type="hidden" name="address[0].PersonId" />
<input type="hidden" name="address[0].CityId" />
<input type="text" name="address[0].Street" />
<input type="text" name="address[0].Building" />
<input type="hidden" name="address[1].Id" />
<input type="hidden" name="address[1].PersonId" />
<input type="hidden" name="address[1].CityId" />
<input type="text" name="address[1].Street" />
<input type="text" name="address[1].Building" />
```

Model Binding will see that these fields conform to the ASP.Net Wire Format, and will bind the values of those fields into a collection of addresses. ref: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Be careful if you start fiddling with the fields using Javascript. If you dynamically add or remove an address block, you must ensure you reset the indexes to start at zero, and the indexes always increment by 1.

Comment: should I bind my view to the Person model or the PersonViewModel ?

Comment: You should bind your View to a ViewModel - that is their purpose! Sometimes your domain model can be used to type your View, but more often than not you want to shape the model your View uses, which is where a ViewModel comes in.

Comment: I cant get the prefix after address ... address[0].Id, all I get is address.ID

Comment: So `Addresses` is a collection, and has multiple addresses in it?

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to use client side approach using knockout as example:
Server side:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new
        {
            person = new { firstName = "123", secondName = "" },
            addresses = new dynamic[1] { new { street = "", building = "", selectedCityId = "" } },
            cities = new dynamic[2] { new { cityName = "Kiev", cityId = "1" }, new { cityName = "Moskow", cityId = "2" } }

        };
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Save(YourType model)
    {
        ..... 
    }

}
```

And client side:

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left:100px">
    <p>First name:</p>
    <input data-bind="value:person.firstName" />

    <p>Second name:</p>
    <input data-bind="value:person.secondName" />
    <h3>Addresses</h3>
    <div data-bind="foreach:addresses">
        <p>
            Street
        </p>
        <input data-bind="value:street" />
        <p>
            Building
        </p>
        <input data-bind="value:building" />
        <p>
            City
        </p>
        <select data-bind="options: $parent.cities, optionsText: 
           'cityName',optionsValue:'cityId',
              value: selectedCityId , optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
        <div>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <button data-bind="click:$parent.add">
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <button style="width:100px"data-bind="click:save">
        Save
    </button>

 </div>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //This create javascript object from your model
    var personModel=@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
    //Parse javascript object to knockout viewModel
    var viewModel=ko.mapping.fromJS(personModel);
    // Create new address
    function Address(){
        this.selectedCityId=ko.observable("");
        this.street=ko.observable("");
        this.building=ko.observable("");
    }
    //Add new address
    viewModel.add=function(){
        viewModel.addresses.push(new Address());

    };
    //Remove address
    viewModel.remove =function(item){
        if(viewModel.addresses().length>1){
            viewModel.addresses.remove(item)
        }         
    };
    //save model
    viewModel.save=function(){
        unmapped=ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel);
        $.post('/home/save',unmapped)
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here some link http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/ that also use this approach.